# Does adding table between dimension and fact in Power BI violate star schema principle and negatively impact model performance?

Tags: powerbi

I have Date, Product and Customer dimensions.

There is 1 fact table called OrderItems. The columns in this table are order_number, order_line item_number, date, productid, customerid, amount. This is a star schema.

I have a new requirement where-in I'm asked to add packaging charges to the model. However this charge is an order level attribute, and not a order item level value. Plus there is a requirement that user must be shown the orders page (list of orders) with charges, and be given ability to select a order and drill through to a new page that shows the order's item details.

So to make this work I have added another fact table called Order with columns: date, productid, customerid, order_num, packaging_charge.

And added another dimension called OrderInfo with order_number. This links to Order and OrderItems on order_number.

Now Date, Customer, Product, and OrderInfo dimensions filter the Order and OrderItems fact tables. This is a star schema.

I want to ask whether this is a good model design, or is it better to let the Date, Customer, Product filter the OrderInfo table, and then let only the OrderInfo table filter Order and OrderItems tables? Does this violate principle of star schema? And which of the above 2 are good data models? Is there a way to better design the model?

Comment: Google header/detail data models.

Comment: They recommend building 1 fact table for the order line but in my situation I have certain value (packaging charge) at order level so I need to have the order table as well